# R - Rolling sum based on dates, with a condition per group

Tags: r, date, datatable, cumulative-sum

I have the following dataset.

[image]

Based on the "start_date_event" of each row, I have already summed up all the days that occurred *within a 60 day range* (variable **sum_days**) from the respective event start date.

However there is a condition that only sums greater than 15 days, for example, must be considered.
*Therefore, for occurrences longer than 15 days I would like to assign "0" to all rows that are part of that respective period.*

**Expected output:**

[image]

Example of expected result: Row 2 has become 0 *as it is contained within the range of the previous row whose sum is greater than fifteen days*. The event recorded in row 2 starts on 2019-02-28, which belongs to the period 2019-01-01 (start of the event) to 2019-03-06 (end of the 60-day interval, 01-01-2019 + 60) of the first row whose sum is greater than 15.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Reproducible example:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

# Input data
data <- data.table(id = c("Group A", "Group A", "Group A", "Group A",
                          "Group B", "Group B"),
                   start_date_event = c("2019-01-01",
                                        "2019-02-28",
                                        "2019-03-13",
                                        "2019-03-19",
                                        "2020-04-02",
                                        "2020-05-15"),
                   end_date_event = c("2019-01-05",
                                      "2019-03-12",
                                      "2019-03-18",
                                      "2019-03-20",
                                      "2020-05-06",
                                      "2020-05-16"))

# Convert to date
data <- data %>%
          dplyr::mutate(start_date_event = as.Date(start_date_event)) %>%
          dplyr::mutate(end_date_event = as.Date(end_date_event)) %>%
          dplyr::mutate(days_diff = as.integer(end_date_event - start_date_event)) %>%
          dplyr::mutate(end_interval = end_date_event + 60) %>%
          data.table::setDT()

# Calculating cumulative sum within 60 days
data[.(c = id, tmin = start_date_event,
       tmax = start_date_event + 60),
   on = .(id == c, start_date_event <= tmax,
          start_date_event >= tmin),
   sum_days := sum(days_diff), by = .EACHI]
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the output, why does the last row become 0?

Comment: How are the respective periods defined? `start_date_event` to `end_interval`?

Comment: @cgvoller The last row should be 0 because it starts (2020-05-15) within the 60-day interval (2020-04-02 to 2020-07-05) of the immediately preceding line whose sum is > 15

Comment: @Matt `start_date_event` represents the start date of a certain event (for example a service). `end_interval` is the result of the sum of 60 days from the `start_date_event`. Calculations are being made considering a 60-day 'window'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
library(sqldf)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

# Creating a new 'row column'
data$row_n <- 1:nrow(data)

# Identifying which lines overlap and then filtering data
data <- sqldf("select a.*, 
                      coalesce(group_concat(b.rowid), '') as overlaps
               from data a
               left join data b on a.id = b.id and 
                                   not a.rowid = b.rowid and
                                   ((a.start_date_event between
                                     b.start_date_event and b.end_interval) or
                                    (b.start_date_event between a.start_date_event
                                     and a.end_interval))
               group by a.rowid
               order by a.rowid") %>%
               group_by(id) %>%
               mutate(row_n = as.character(row_n),
                      previous_row = dplyr::lag(row_n, n = 1, default = NA),
                      previous_value = dplyr::lag(sum_days, n = 1, default = NA),
                      sum2 = case_when(mapply(grepl,previous_row, overlaps) == TRUE &
                                         previous_value > 15 ~ as.integer(0),
                                       TRUE ~ sum_days),
                      previous_value = dplyr::lag(sum2, n = 1, default = NA),
                      sum2 = case_when(mapply(grepl,previous_row, overlaps) == TRUE &
                                         previous_value > 15 ~ as.integer(0),
                                       TRUE ~ sum_days)) %>%
               dplyr::select(-c(previous_value, previous_row, row_n))
```